# Does couchbase 3.0 support transaction?

Tags: couchbase

- couchbase config

host:
ip:127.0.0.1 port:17000

buckets:
Bucket1 Bucket2 Bucket3

I want to set 3 buckets {set(Bucket1), set(Bucket2), set(Bucket3)} as a transaction.

How should I do to implement?

Comment: Why have you a need for transactions?

Comment: one big entity composed by 3 small entity.the big entity must init as a whole.and the small entity has "key:value" attribute.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't save them all inside one document?

Comment: yes,I have to separate it.There are 4 kinds of "key" query.

Comment: I really can't think of a case where a query would drive a need to split apart related entities into separate documents. If anything, it is a reason _not_ to separate. In any case, perhaps Couchbase is not the best option for your use-case?

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is 'no'. Couchbase does not support transactions across different documents. As theMayer mentioned, you might avoid the need for transactions by modelling your data differently. However, if you must have it, you can use two phase commit to get part of the transaction functionality (the atomicity and durability, but not isolation or consistency.)

You can read up on 2PC in general here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol and specifically as it relates to Couchbase here: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#performing-two-phase-commits

Answer (score 6):

As of [Couchbase Server 6.5](https://blog.couchbase.com/announcing-couchbase-server-6-5-0-beta-whats-new-and-improved/) (in beta as of this writing), there is a way to atomically modify multiple documents in a single [transaction](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-brings-distributed-multi-document-acid-transactions-to-nosql/).  Chances are you will want to model this as documents in different collections.